# Windows batch way to replace all files in subdirectories with singular file (copy, rename all files)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a good command over `cmd` commands, but this may require a variable or a loop which is where I fail in batch commands. Please help if you can!

-- Have about 100 subdirectories each has 1-20 HTML files in it. There are about 100 HTML files in the root directory too.
-- Need to replace all HTML files in the above directories with the same HTML source (copy over existing file and keep the name the same). Basically trying to replace all existing files with a redirect script to a new server for direct bookmarked people. We are running a plain webserver without access to server-side redirects so trying to do this just by renaming the files (locked down corp environment).

Seems pretty simple. I can't get it to work with wildcards by copying the same file over to replace. I only get the first file replaced, but the rest of the files will fail. Any one with any advice?

Comment: Can you give an example of the original text and how you want the text changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it from the command prompt.  Replace `%` with `%%` for use in a batch file.

```
for /r "c:\base\folder" %a in (*.html) do copy /y "d:\redirect.html" "%a"
```

Comment: THANK YOU very much -- this simple command prompt line did the trick. Much kudos!!!

Comment: That's neat.  I didn't properly understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more precisely how you want to update the file content I suggest the following rough approach.

To re-create your example, I had to create some folders.  Run this command to do that:

```
for /l %i in (1,1,20) do mkdir fold%i
```

I then used this script to create some example files:

```
@echo off
set number=0
for /d %%i in (c:\Logs\htmltest\*) do call :makefiles %%i
goto :EOF

:makefiles
set /a number+=1
touch %1\file%number%.txt
echo %number% >%1\file%number%.txt
```

I then used this script to append the text changed to the file.  Not sure if that is what you wanted - probably you need something more sophisticated.

```
@echo off
set number=0
for /d %%i in (c:\Logs\htmltest\*) do @for %%f in ("%%i\*.txt") do call :changetext %%f
goto :EOF

:changetext
echo changing file contents to ^"changed^" for file: %1
echo changed>>%1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write this up. I think it is a little more sophisticated for what I needed to do, but hopefully it will help someone else.